# Create new Excel rows based on column Heading and populate the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create output XLS file based on input xls file header. I am giving below exact requirement. hope its clear. if not then please let me know.

```
Iput XLS -->
ID  Version NameLegacy  ProjectNumber   OwnerName   Language    Keywords    OwnerSite   External    Content Relevance   Periodic    Coremap ValidTo
1   1   Mohan   1000    x   ENG ABCD    AB  No  ok  no  5   2017-10-14  2018-10-14
2   2   Shayam  1001    y   ENG EFGH    BC  No  ok  yes 2   2017-10-14  2018-10-14
3   1   Sourabh 1002    z   ENG IJKL    CD  Yes no  no  4   2017-10-14  2018-10-14
```

Based on this Input XLS File, i need Output XLS File as below. Each row of input file will have 12 row of output file and respective value will be filled in Output file from input file.

```
ID  Version IBANAME STRINGVALUE INTEGERVALUE    FLOATVALUE  FLOATVALUEWITHUNITS BOOLVALUE   TIMEVALUE   URLVALUE    REFERENCEVALUE
1   1   NameLegacy  Mohan                           
1   1   ProjectNumber           1000                            
1   1   OwnerName   x                           
1   1   Language    ENG                         
1   1   Keywords    ABCD                            
1   1   OwnerSite                                                                                       AB                          
1   1   External                                                                No          
1   1   Content                                                                                                     ok                          
1   1   Relevance                                                               no                          
1   1   Periodic                5                           
1   1   Coremap                                                                              2017-10-14     
1   1   ValidTo                                                                              2018-10-14     
2   2   NameLegacy  Shayam                          
2   2   ProjectNumber           1001                            
2   2   OwnerName   y                           
2   2   Language    ENG                         
2   2   Keywords    EFGH                            
2   2   OwnerSite                                                                                       BC                          
2   2   External                                                                No          
2   2   Content                                                                                                     ok                          
2   2   Relevance                                                               yes                         
2   2   Periodic                2                           
2   2   Coremap                                                                              2017-10-14     
2   2   ValidTo                                                                              2018-10-14     
3   1   NameLegacy  Sourabh                         
3   1   ProjectNumber           1002                            
3   1   OwnerName   z                           
3   1   Language    ENG                         
3   1   Keywords    IJKL                            
3   1   OwnerSite                                                                                       CD                          
3   1   External                                                                Yes         
3   1   Content                                                                                                     no                          
3   1   Relevance                                                               no                          
3   1   Periodic                4                           
3   1   Coremap                                                                              2017-10-14     
3   1   ValidTo                                                                              2018-10-14
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few steps to do this using VBA.  The main purpose is to identify what you are actually trying to do.

It seems like you are attempting to sort through records to identify what the format of the information is and place it in a column designated for only that format.  To do this, I have created a very simple custom Function..

This function takes in the name of the header as a string, and uses Select/Case to find appropriate matches for which column the target sheet needs.  This is custom to your specific layout.  Feel free to adapt or change it.

**FUNCTION TO FIND CORRECT COLUMN ON TARGET**

```
Function ColFinder(header As String) As Long


'Target Column Format = Column #

'"STRINGVALUE"        = 4
'"INTEGERVALUE"       = 5
'"FLOATVALUE"         = 6
'"FLOATVALUEWITHUNITS"= 7
'"BOOLVALUE"          = 8
'"TIMEVALUE"          = 9
'"URLVALUE"           = 10
'"REFERENCEVALUE"     = 11


' **** SET VALUES FOR CASES TO MATCH DESIRED FORMAT ABOVE  ****

'Default to Column 4 StringValue if unknown
    Select Case header
        Case "NameLegacy"
            ColFinder = 4
        Case "ProjectNumber"
            ColFinder = 5
        Case "OwnerName"
            ColFinder = 4
        Case "Language"
            ColFinder = 4
        Case "Keywords"
            ColFinder = 4
        Case "OwnerSite"
            ColFinder = 10
        Case "External"
            ColFinder = 8
        Case "Content"
            ColFinder = 11
        Case "Relevance"
            ColFinder = 8
        Case "Periodic"
            ColFinder = 5
        Case "Coremap"
            ColFinder = 9
        Case "ValidTo"
            ColFinder = 9
    End Select

End Function
```

Using a few other Functions for finding Last Row & Last Column

**Last Row Function**

```
Function lastRow(sheet As String) As Long

    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'Using Cells()

End Function
```

**Last Column Function**

```
Function lastCol(sheet As String) As Long

    lastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function
```

With these three functions, you can run a simple loop through the source sheet, one row at a time, then look to see which column the data is coming from, and place it on the appropriate target.

**This example is using two worksheets in the same workbook.**  To change, just extend the address to include other workbooks or sheets.  This is just the simplest way to show the concept.

**CODE TO LOOP THROUGH SHEETS**

```
Sub ColsToRows()

Dim tRow As Long, sCol As Long, sRow As Long
Dim source As String, target As String
Dim tString As String

source = "Sheet1"
target = "Sheet2"

'Set target Row starting point
tRow = 2

    'Loop through Source Rows with Data, starting after Header Row
    For sRow = 2 To lastRow(source)

        'Loop through each header in Source Row
        For sCol = 3 To lastCol(source)

            'Set Basic Columns on Target
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 1) = Sheets(source).Cells(sRow, 1)
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 2) = Sheets(source).Cells(sRow, 2)

            'Get Header Name as Temp String to find which format it requires
            tString = Sheets(source).Cells(1, sCol)

            'Label Column 3 of Target
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 3) = Sheets(source).Cells(1, sCol)

            'Find Appropriate Column using custom Formula [ColFinder(header As String) As Long]
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, ColFinder(tString)) = Sheets(source).Cells(sRow, sCol)

            'Advance to next Target Row
            tRow = tRow + 1

        Next sCol

    Next sRow

End Sub
```

**Source Sheet Example**
[image: Source Sheet]

**Target Sheet Example**
[image: Target Sheet]

Comment: Hi.. Thanks a lot.. the VBA code you suggested and based on the O/P has come exactly that's my requirement. I have total almost 1 Lac plus records are there. I am totally new to VBA and macro never used it. But your solution is great which serves my purpose. 
So it would be a great help if you can elaborate more thinking i am totally new and how and where to write the code so that i can get the o/p as required. Thanks a TON in advance.

Comment: F11 for Development Console, then Insert Module.  Copy and paste into the module and change any specifics like sheet names.  you can assign shapes or images to the sub as a macro, or you can just run the code from the Dev Console.  There's plenty of online tutorials that can help you though.  Do a google search for Excel VBA tutorials.  It's easier than reading this comment and trying to make sense of the code.  In the long run, you will save more time learning it than trying to modify other people's code.  It's easy.

Comment: Thanks @peege for your help. Your suggestion of VBA was awesome. I have modified the code based on my requirement and it was successful. Thanks a TON for your help. :) I am stuck in another issue in loading the data from one sheet to another sheet. If you could help me through VBA. I have asked for help in another Question... i am also trying.

Comment: hi.. @peege when I am adding one more column in sheet1 and sheet2.. its giving error.... :(
'Find Appropriate Column using custom Formula [ColFinder(header As String) As Long]
            Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, ColFinder(tString)) = Sheets(source).Cells(sRow, sCol)

Comment: You have to add those columns to the custom function ColFinder and point them to the correct target column .   For example, string values end on column "d" or (4).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the upper table to the lower one using formulas within Excel.

We start from defining all the input range, without the first 2 columns and the headers row as a range named `input`. This is done by selecting all the range and typing "input" in the "Name box":
[image: Define input range]

Create the following table where you like in the workbook, then define it all and a range named `col_index`:

```
STRINGVALUE INTEGERVALUE    FLOATVALUE  FLOATVALUEWITHUNITS BOOLVALUE   TIMEVALUE   URLVALUE    REFERENCEVALUE
NameLegacy  ProjectNumber                                   External    Coremap     OwnerSite   Content
OwnerName   Periodic                                        Relevance   ValidTo     
Language                            
Keywords
```

[image: col_index range]

This table basically sorts the original columns into their new place. You can add values, rows or columns to the table and it will stay intact, as long as you keep *all* of it under the name range `col_index`.

Then create another table headers:

```
ID  Version IBANAME STRINGVALUE INTEGERVALUE    FLOATVALUE  FLOATVALUEWITHUNITS BOOLVALUE   TIMEVALUE   URLVALUE    REFERENCEVALUE
```

Now paste the following formulas in the first row in each of column 1-4:

1. ID: `=IF(C2=sheet1!$C$1,A1+1,A1)`
2. Version: `=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet1!$A$1:$B$4,2)`
3. after selecting the first 12 rows under IBANAME, press F2, and paste: `=TRANSPOSE(sheet1!C1:N1)` as [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)! (press ctrl+shift+enter after pasting to the formula box)
4. STRINGVALUE: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($C16,OFFSET(col_index,0,MATCH(D$15,OFFSET(col_index,0,0,1,11),0)-1,5,1),0)-1),"",OFFSET(input,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($D$16))/COLUMNS(input)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($D$16),COLUMNS(input)),1,1))`

Next, drag columns `ID` and `Version` 12 rows down, to the next ID (row 14), then change the value in cell `A2` to `1`, and the value in `C14` to `=C2`, and continue dragging columns `ID`, `Version` and `IBANAME` until the end of the data is reached. Finally, drag the cell `D2` left to the end of the row, and then down to fill all the table.

This it how it looks with formulas:
[image: Vectorizing table - formulas]

And this is with values:

[image: Vectorizing table - values]

That's it ;)

Comment: HI.. Thanks a lot. For StringValue i am not getting might be i am missing something. what is input for STRINGVALUE ? WHere do declare it ? =OFFSET(input,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($D$2))/COLUMNS(input)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($D$2),COLUMNS(input)),1,1)

Comment: The question is not formatted in a way that is clear.  The poster is asking for each data type to be in its own column on the target sheet.  It just looks like they are all StringValues...  but the columns aren't spaced in example.  1000 would be IntegerValue, the Date is a time, etc.  bool is Yes, No,.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. But what i have given is the same requirement. Considering Project Number is STRING only... might be i have given example as 1000 which created confusion. Please consider this and request help. I am totally new.. so please help me how and where to write the code so that i can get desired output. Thanks a ton for your quick response.

Comment: @user6622113 I see now what you meant (and edited your question properly), and I have edited my answer to fit this requirements. So if you don't feel  like VBA, and prefer solving it by formulas - you have a choice ;)

Comment: Thanks @EBH for your prompt response. Now I am glad to know 2 option for one problem. Once again Thanks. :)

Comment: @user6622113 if this answer can solve your question, please upvote it, so future readers can know that's there's an eligible non-VBA way to do that ;)